# Firefox -- "FileReader is not defined" only when called from Web Worker

Tags: javascript, firefox, filereader, web-worker, fileapi

In Firefox, the following code works correctly when run in the main browser thread as normal--

```
var fr = new FileReader();
```

..but when run from a web worker, the following error is thrown:

```
FileReader is not defined
```

The same code works fine in Chrome and Safari.

Any suggestions for supporting FileReader in a web worker in Firefox?

Comment: Did you try using `FileReaderSync` instead of `FileReader` ?

Comment: @adeneo, yes, that does appear to be supported. Does FF not support asynchronous file reading? Are chrome/safari actually operating synchronously when I use FileReader?

Comment: Well, `FileReaderSync` is *only* supported in workers, as you generally don't need asynchronous file reading in a worker, but I'm not sure why Firefox doesn't support the regular async `FileReader` in worker, I thought they did, but at least they support the synchronous version, so you can just use that as you don't need async behaviour in a worker anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As adeneo pointed out, it seems that `FileReader` is simply not supported by Firefox in Web Workers. I was able to use `FileReaderSync` instead to accomplish what I needed.

Comment: The bug request on bugzilla related to the Firefox shortcoming https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=901097

Comment: Web workers are especially for blocking, intensive tasks which may block the main thread giving a poor user experience (UI blocking etc). 

That's probably why Firefox has focused on implementing FileReaderSync in Workers before FileReader, it just makes more sense in the Web Worker context.